# Combine two tables without repeat second table value

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables that need to be joined.

Example:

```
Table 1: tbl_Item

Id ---- ItemName   

1  -----  A<br/>
1  -----  B<br/>
1  -----  c<br/>
2  -----  A<br/>
2  -----  B<br/>


Table 2: tbl_Detail

Id ---- Total

1  ---- 100 <br/>
2  ---- 300<br/>
```

I need to join the tables and get the following result:

```
Id -- ItemName --  Total

1  --  A  ---      Null<br/>
1  --  B  ---      Null<br/>
1  --  C  ---      100<br/>
2  --  A  ---      Null<br/>
2  --  B  ---      300<br/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain the rules.  Remember:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no first or last row in a group.

Comment: You can use "join" property of SQL...See this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @Jay can you tell me why you there is single "id" for many "item name"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the `total` value to an *indeterminate* single row by using `row_number()`:

```
select t.id, t.ItemName,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by t.id order by (select NULL)) = 1
             then d.total
        end) as total
from tbl_item t join
     tbl_detail d
     on t.id = d.id;
```

If you have an ordering (probably specified by another column), then replace `(select null)` with the appropriate logic.  For the example data, for instance, you might use `i.name desc`, but I doubt that is the actual ordering you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT Id, ItemName, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ItemName DESC) AS rn
   FROM  tbl_Item
) 
SELECT t1.Id, t1.ItemName, 
       CASE WHEN t1.rn = 1 THEN t2.Total END AS Total
FROM CTE AS t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_Detail AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```